# EventEmitter на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, классы, события

Реализовал простенький EventEmitter через классы, однако почему-то реализация методов off и once не проходят автотесты. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

```
    class EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        this.events = {};
    }

    on(eventName, callback) {
        this.events[eventName] = this.events[eventName] || [];
        this.events[eventName].push(callback);
        return this;
    }

    off(eventName, callback) {
        let event = this.events[eventName];
        if (!event) return this;
        for (let i = event.length; i > 0; i--) {
            if (event[i] === callback) {
                event.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
        return this;
    }

    once(eventName, callback) {
        this.events[eventName] = this.events[eventName] || [];
        const onceEvent = () => {
            callback();
            this.off(eventName, onceEvent);
        }
        this.events[eventName].push(onceEvent);
        return this;
    }

    emit(eventName, ...args) {
        let fns = this.events[eventName];
        if (!fns) return false;
        fns.forEach((fn) => {
          fn.call(null, args);
        });
        return true;
    }
}
```

Также необходимо расширить класс EventEmitter классом BroadcastEventEmitter так, чтобы была возможность вызвать все обработчики всех событий.

```
emit("*", [...arg])
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не работают методы off и once, в чем проблема?

Comment: В once нет передачи параметров в коллбэк.

Comment: Нет, не так. Проблема была в методе off, он не выполнял условие в if, из-за этого не выполнялся once как надо. Если заменить в off цикл на this.events[eventName].splice(callback, 1), то отработает как надо, разобрался сам. Вопрос теперь во второй части, как реализовать выполнение всех обработчиков всех событий?

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум стоит реализовать метод off по аналогии с on

```
off(eventName, callback) {
        if (!this.events[eventName]) return 'no'
        delete this.events[eventName];
        return this.events;
    }
```